# Elasticsearch query on IDs with message filtering + not exists filter on different message

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to query some Elastisearch logs based on message and id.

The simplified scenario is the following: each minute a case is worked. If it is completed we have a log "COMPLETED", otherwise "NOT COMPLETED".

Cases can be reprocessed, so a NON-COMPLETED case can be COMPLETED the next time it is worked.
I want to retrieve all the cases NOT COMPLETED yet.

A sample datatable is:

```
message         CASE_ID
COMPLETED         008
COMPLETED         004
NOT COMPLETED     004
NOT COMPLETED     002
COMPLETED         006
NOT COMPLETED     002
COMPLETED         001
```

In the above example I would need to retrieve case 002 which has not been completed yet. (chronological order is from bottom to top)

In SQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT CASE_ID
FROM logs l1
WHERE l1.message = "NOT COMPLETED"
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      CASE_ID
    FROM
      logs l2
    WHERE
      l2.message = "COMPLETED"
      AND l1.CASE_ID = l2.CASE_ID
  )
```

I am new to ElastiSearch and after reading some examples I have tried different aggregations but they did not work.

Thanks to anyone who will help

Comment: At a give instant `message` can be either `COMPLETED` or `NOT COMPLETED` then why there is a requirement of `NOT EXISTS` in the query? It would be better if you can add a few sample records and tell which of those are expected to be counted by the query.

Comment: Hi Nishant thanks for answering. I've added a sample datatable that could clarify the description

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done in a single elasticsearch query. It would be better to rethink about the storage schema. If you want that as an answer I'll add it?

Comment: What do you mean by storage schema? Those are the logs from which I want to extract information with ElasticSearch. "CASE_ID" is another indexed field.
I can also try to search the logs structured as "CASE xxxx completed" or "CASE yyyy NOT COMPLETED" but I think it is more complicated than the approach I described above.

Comment: Make case id as document id. Since at a given instant of time it can hold either of the two status. So your index will have only one document per case id and holds it's latest status. In this case you can simply get the case ids with status NOT COMPLETE.

Comment: Ok, how can I do that? From the "management" Menu in Kibana?